Why am I getting an IBMRuntimeError when trying to run my Session?
I followed a Qiskit tutorial and am trying to run my code on a QPU, but I am getting a session time-out error.
I am trying to implement the QAOA and run it on a QPU. I first ran my code on a simulator and it worked perfectly fine. To run it on a QPU, I followed a Qiskit tutorial. The job requires multiple job submissions, so they use a Session.
QAOA Qiskit tutorial (https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm)
When running the code, it's pending for almost half an hour, and then I am getting a runtime error. It says something about the need to reduce time between job submissions.
I don't understand what I need to do to get my job to run.
I would appreciate some insight on why this might be happeningg and how to solve it.
My job submission code:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, EstimatorV2 as Estimator
from scipy.optimize import minimize

objective_func_vals = []
with Session(backend=backend) as session:
   estimator = Estimator(mode=session)
   estimator.options.default_shots = 1000

# use error mitigation
   estimator.options.dynamical_decoupling.enable = True
   estimator.options.dynamical_decoupling.sequence_type = "XY4"
   estimator.options.twirling.enable_gates = True
   estimator.options.twirling.num_randomizations = "auto"

   result = minimize(
       cost_func_estimator,
       init_params,
       args=(candidate_circuit, cost_hamiltonian, estimator),
       method="COBYLA",
       tol=1e-2,
   )
   print(result)

The error I am getting:
IBMRuntimeError: 'Failed to run program: \\'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.quantum.ibm.com/runtime/jobs. {\"errors\":[{\"code\":1217,\"message\":\"Session has been closed.\",\"solution\":\"Reduce time between submitting subsequent jobs in a session.\",\"more_info\":\"https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/errors\"}]}\\''"


Can you post the whole code you use to submit to a QPU?

Hi, the error you're getting is popping because you're trying to submit jobs to a session that has been closed and doesn't accept jobs anymore. This shouldn't happen if you use the exact same code as the one in the tutorial you point, because there the session is created with a context manager, which is handling for you the clean opening and closing of the session. As said in the previous comment, having the code snippet of how you send your jobs through the session would be more than useful to help you debug this, could you share it please? :)

@Lena thank you for replying. I added the code snippet to the post! I see what you are saying. I just tried copying and pasting the exact same code from the tutorial and opening a new Session, I am still getting the same error. I'm not getting what the issue is. Maybe the jobs inside the session are not running properly?

@TristanNemoz thank you for replying. I added the code snippet to the post.

Could you share your full code?
